# Simple JQuery effects not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to StackOverflow but I have a simple question about jQuery effects.

I'm trying to implement a function that slide toggles a navigation bar when an icon is clicked. However, it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="navbutton"><img src="navbutton.png" style="width: 15px"></a></li>
<li class="nav">One</li>
<li class="nav">Two</li>
<li class="nav">Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    function runEffect() {
      $( "#navigation .nav" ).toggle("slide", 500);
    };

    $( "#navbutton" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you referencing jquery anywhere in your html?

Comment: What is `$("#navigation.nav")` supposed to select? I think you want `$("#navigation .nav")`.

Comment: is the dom ready? is jquery already loaded?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Here's my code from the html head

`<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/homepage.js">
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, use the CSS descendent selector by inserting a space between `#navigation` and `.nav`

```
$( "#navigation .nav" ).toggle(500);
```

To include an easing option you would pass in the options as an object.

```
$( "#navigation .nav" ).toggle({ easing: 'slide', duration: 500 });
```

However as stated in another post, the easing function `slide` is provided by JqueryUI, `swing` is the default provided by jQuery.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEdj9/)

Comment: I fixed this but this is not the problem. (I had a different selector at first and changed it outside of the editor and forgot to include the space)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("#navigation.nav")` to `$("#navigation li.nav")` and the "slide" method of easing requires [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n65e7/)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="navbutton">
                <img src="~/Content/navlogo.png" onclick="ShowNav();" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">One</li>
        <li class="nav">Two</li>
        <li class="nav">Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
function ShowNav() {
    $("#navigation").slideToggle(500);
};
```